# ¿Qué refrán inglés es equivalente a "sarna con gusto no pica"?

Tags: traducción, refranes

Hace unas semanas me rompí la clavícula en pedazos al caer de mi bici de montaña. Durante el tiempo que estaba ingresado en el hospital, tres personas diferentes me han dicho:

> sarna con gusto no pica

por mi actitud, que es, basicamente, "esto duele mucho, pero vivo por y para el deporte y no voy a cambiar nada". Si esto parece egoísta, tengo seguro médico, así que, no cuesta nada a los contribuyentes a las arcas públicas :-)

La pregunata es cómo se traduce esta frase al Inglés. Creo que es algo como

> Don't do the crime, if you won't do the time

o

> If you've got an itch, you've got to scratch it

o una combinación de las dos. "Nice scabies does not itch" suena muy raro en Inglés.

Comment: ¡Espero que estés ya plenamente recuperado!

Comment: Bueno, si recuperado significa empezar a entrenar un Ironman, pues sí. Mi esposa diría que tengo problemas mentales bastante graves

Comment: Por cierto, nótese que el título de la pregunta no se corresponde con lo que preguntas después: lo que quieres saber es cuál es el equivalente en inglés a "sarna con gusto no pica", porque el significado de la expresión sí lo conoces, ¿verdad?

Comment: Vale, la verdad es que no. Estoy buscando el refrán en inglés que es más cerca al significado de sarna con gusto no pica. Puse las dos opciones que me parece más probable por el contexto pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: No me parece en absoluto parecido a «*Don't do the crime*». Ese significa que hay que aceptar las consecuencias de tus acciones, pero «*sarna con gusto no pica*» significa que todo se puede soportar si la recompensa es suficiente.

Comment: @PeterTaylor. Pues, puedes sugerir algo parecido en inglés?

Comment: No, o habría dejado una respuesta en vez de un comentario.

Comment: Sí, vale. Puede que no exista un refrán inglés con el sentido exacto. Ahora entiendo que significa en español, describe totalmente mi actitud a la bici y vivo en Barcelona, pues estoy contento.

Comment: @walen, go ahead and close it, there is an accepted answer. It strikes me as pointless and demasiado riguroso, but if it makes you feel better.

Comment: @Walen. Fair enough. I am  close to  becoming an admin  on GIS.SE, so will have to start taking decisions like this myself soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como [comenta el Centro Virtual Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=59505&Lng=0), el significado de esta expresión es:

> Quien que va tras algo de forma voluntaria, no siente molestias por
>   las posibles incomodidades.

En tu caso particular está muy bien usada la expresión, pues eres un poco kamikaze (con cariño ;) ) y tienes accidentes. Como el deporte extremo es algo que te gusta practicar, la molestia que te ocasionan los accidentes que tienes no es tal como para impedirte seguir haciéndolo. Consejo de padre: ¡ve con cuidado!

En [Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sarna-con-gusto-no-pica.561659/) he encontrado un par de traducciones al inglés que no son literales, sino que mantienen el sentido del refrán:

- If you love scabies, they don't hurt
- If you like the scratching then you do not mind the lice

Probablemente necesitamos algún angloparlante para confirmar que sí son refranes típicos y con el mismo significado. Mis búsquedas me indican que parece que sí.

Comment: Gracias. Estoy angloparlante y es por eso que adiviné entre los dos refranes inglés por el contexto en que me han dicho el refrán en español. La traducción más o menos literal no es correcto.

Comment: "*Soy* angloparlante" :) ¿Con "no es correcto" te refieres a que lo que comento no son dichos en inglés?

Comment: Si. He cambiado la pregunta. Espero que sea más claro.

Comment: @JohnBarça edité para añadir una explicación del significado de la expresión en castellano.

Comment: Creo que en este caso, el inglés más cercano sería "don't do the crime, if you won't do the time".  Gracias.